# Windows Defender turned off by Group Policy

Tags: windows-10, administrator, anti-virus, group-policy, windows-defender

My PC with *Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB v.1607* installed, automatically restarted for an error (I don't remember the error, I just remember a blue page in Windows style with a sad emoticon face).
When the PC restarted, Windows defender was disabled and I'm not able to turn it on. 
The error is:

> Windows Defender is Turned off by Group Policy.  To protect your computer
>   against harmful or potentially unwanted software, contact your system
>   administrator to enable Windows Defender via group policy.

I've tried all the following things:

1. Delete the value in the `DisableAntiSpyware` key in `HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender` (I've not this key because my version is older than v.1703).
2. In `Local Computer Policy > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender` the option `Turn off Windows Defender` is already set to `not configured`.
3. In `Services` the service  `Windows Defender` is not present.
4. In `Control Panel > Action Center` under the voice `Windows Firewall` I can read: `For your security, some settings are managed by your system administrator`, but I'm the administrator.

How can I turn on Windows Defender?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT The answer in no to both questions. I think DrMoishe Pippik's answer is the right one.

Comment: Yokay............... Be sure to stay protected in this Internet ocean!!

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I thought I was so. I use Windows Defender and more than once a week I use Malwarebytes. In Firefox I use uBlock Origin and Adblock Plus among other add-ons. Do you suggest me other measures to follow in addition to common sense?

Comment: Maybe just ensure you have antimalware protection as well such as https://www.malwarebytes.com/ but go ahead and use the free version and the 14-day trial of premium if you want. Common sense and good judgement is going to be the big one for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds more like malware than an accidental change to Group Policy, since [that switch is normally *not* used by AV suites to disable Defender](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_scanning-windows_10/windows-defender-is-blocked-by-group-policy/27dcfbeb-9042-401c-8b2a-56cc681757cc?auth=1). If you cannot reset that in GPE, then make bootable media to scan for malware, e.g. [Avira Rescue System](https://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system), [Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool](http://devbuilds.kaspersky-labs.com/devbuilds/KVRT/latest/full/KVRT.exe) or [Rescue Disk](https://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk#downloads).

You might also try installing a third party AV suite, such as the free versions of [Avast!](https://www.avast.com/en-us/index), [Avira](https://www.avira.com/en/free-antivirus-windows) or [alternatives](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2388652,00.asp) to see if that corrects the issue. You would then have the choice of staying with that AV suite or uninstalling it to see if Defender works again.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right. Even if at the momet that the problem occurred no antivirus et similia find anything, two days ago I founded to be infected by Trojan.BitcoinMiner malware. Now I think (and hope) I've removed it and Windows Defender works fine.

Comment: Note on BitCoin miners: not only are there independent applications, but there are miners that run inside a browser. Be sure your internet browser is immunized, too. https://medium.com/@MaxenceCornet/coinhive-review-embeddable-javascript-crypto-miner-806f7024cde8